# Navbar not displaying in mobile-view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a little stuck, my website looks fine when viewed on a browser, but in mobile view the entire nav bar has been removed.

```css
@media only screen and  (min-width: 992px) {
    .navbar .nav-item .dropdown-menu {
        display: none;
        animation: growOut 300ms ease-in-out forwards;
        transform-origin: top center;
    }
    @keyframes growOut {
        0% {
            transform: scale(0)
        }
        80% {
            transform: scale(1.1)
        }
        100% {
            transform: scale(1)
        }
    }
    .navbar .nav-item:hover .nav-link {}
    .navbar .nav-item:hover .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar .nav-item .dropdown-menu {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: check if your navbar is visible. try to add `.navbar { display: block !important; visibility: visible !important; }`

Comment: if not work try to set the height and the width, something like `.navbar { height: 90px !important; width: 100vw !important; )`

Comment: if the first sugestion works, it means that somewhere in your code you manipulate the display mode or the visibility of the navbar. check it and adapt the code.

Comment: if the second sugestion works, it means that somewhere in your code you manipulate the size of the navbar. check it and adapt the code.

Comment: Hello Taur, thank you for the responses. I tried both, and have had no luck. Even in my browser when I resize the window to a narrow view, the menu disappears :(

Comment: put your code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) and share it with us.

Answer (score 1):

You got display none on your media query, depending on your mobile device's size, most likely your query allows you to see it on your computer but not on your mobile device.